# Submissions in Pehlwani?

Tags: grappling, wrestling, submissions, pehlwani

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pehlwani), in (some rulesets of) the Indian grappling sport Pehlwani, one can win with locks and submissions. However, English language [resources](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9882/pehlwani-manuals-technique-descriptions) on the techniques of Pehlwani are very limited.

What submissions are allowed/taught in Pehlwani?

Comment: Video example of throwing techniques: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ1T4CONLWI

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both strangles and joint-locks are traditional techniques in various schools of Indian wrestling.

However, in some schools there are restrictions on their use and they may only be employed as compliance techniques to manipulate the opponent into a pin (as in collegiate wrestling), as opposed to submitting outright (like in judo, bjj):

> We find four principle schools of Wrestling viz:-
>
> 1. Hanumanti ,
> 2. Jambuwanti,
> 3. Jarasandhi and
> 4. Bhimseni.
>
> The holds referred to in this volume belong to the last school. The feature of the branch concerned in this book is the entire absence of the old 'fury' element as its code strictly prohibits foul holds, butting, picking, **strangling, bone-breaking** and deliberate attempts to disable an opponent (when a fall could under no circumstances be secured.)

- [The Science of Wrestling, Vol. 1](https://archive.org/details/dli.csl.6009/page/n9/mode/2up) (1927).

Nonetheless the above volume details several strangle and joint-lock techniques:

| [image] | [image] [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Rear naked choke](https://www.reddit.com/r/bjj/comments/hvsj6d/rnc_in_a_kushti_book_of_techniques_from_1927/) | Rear Naked choke | [Omoplata](https://www.grapplearts.com/the-ancient-vale-tudo-of-india-vajramushti/#) | Triangle |