# Manual of Pehlwani techniques?

Tags: technique, books, pehlwani

Are there any manuals or similar resources describing Pehlwani techniques (preferably in English or Hindi)?

Comment: E.g. some tackles: *dhobi, puthhi, saaltu, bagaldoop*.

Comment: I did a bit of poking around, but the best I've found so far are some partially translated Iranian texts in the parallel Pahlwani style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehensive manual seems to be [*The Science of Wrestling, Vol. 1*](https://archive.org/details/dli.csl.6009) (1927). It details throws, pins, chokes, joint locks, counters, combinations, and entries:

| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Further resources are detailed below:

#### Textbooks

- Pehlwani: Identity, Ideology and the Body of the Indian Wrestler, [Vol. 1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6ZRHAQAAMAAJ), [Vol. 2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nZRHAQAAMAAJ) (1989)
- [Wrestling in Indi: Indian Wrestlers, Indian Wrestling Coaches, Pehlwani](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Wrestling_in_Indi.html?id=tBuySgAACAAJ) (2010)
- [The Wrestler's body: Identity and Ideology in North India](https://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=ft6n39p104;brand=eschol) (1992)

#### Documentaries

- [Punjabi Wrestling](http://www.panjabiwrestling.org.uk/film.html) (2019)

Comment: Excellent work!